# Stalled GCR Builds

Tags: google-container-registry

I'm seeing stalled builds on GCR and I don't know how to debug.  My last three builds have stalled at installing a YUM package fairly early into the build process.  The packages are not exotic: libXrender, libfontenc, etc.

I think our timeout is set to 43200s or 12 hours.  Is it possible the GCR builders are stalled because we consumed all the HD space ?  Does anyone know what the resources are for a given GCR builder machine?

Comment: Could you give any repro steps or details about your build? A build ID could be helpful too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I was slammed with a bit o work.  BUILD IDs: 
- c89ea9a3-3186-4153-a6a0-d4fc89fc3fb9
- 766da161-e347-440d-9955-ee4edd3dad2e